# JAXB Does not Marshall as Expected

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

A buddy of mine asked me to post this question:

EDIT: He decided to post the question on his own here: [JAXB Unmarshalls XML Incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916790/jaxb-unmarshalls-xml-incorrectly)  I tried to delete this question but couldn't.

I am trying to marshall a java class, called `MyContainer`. This class extends my another class, called `Container`. `Container` has a variable called: `protected List<ResourceReference<Component>> child`

The only variable `MyContainer` has is the one it inherits from `Container`. This `List`, however, will not marshall with JAXB when I have child listed as an `XmlList`.

It will marshall as an `XmlElement`, however this is not how I want the data displayed.  When it is marshalled as an `XmlElement`, it  lists the attributes in the `List`, but not 'heirarchially' It just lists the two elements as if they were properties of the class, as opposed to belonging to the child list.

How do I get Jaxb to marshall the `List` (Which is instantiated as an ArrayList) correctly?

EDIT: Here's an example:
This is what I am getting:

```
<MyContainer name="Container Name">
    <booleanVal>false</booleanVal>
    <child id="Test Comp 1"/>
    <child id="Test Comp 2"/>
</and>
```

This is more what I expect:

```
<MyContainer name="Container Name">
    <booleanVal>false</booleanVal>
    <child> /// This would be the class variable of the extended Class, Container
        <ResourceRef id="Entry 1">
        <ResourceRef id="Entry 2">
    </child>
</and>
```

Admittly, my current results is probably from the List in Container being marked with the @XmlElement annotation. However, JAXB will not marshall anything else..

Comment: It's hard to follow your question.  Can you give a sample of the XML you're getting and another sample of the XML you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate your list with `@XmlElementWrapper`. See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html).

Comment: `@XmlElementWrapper` does display the data correctly, however when JAXB goes to Demarshall that XML file, it doesnt not properly insert the elements into the list. What am I missing to have it identify each thing listed within the wrapper as an element in the list?

Comment: My friend decided to post his question.  See it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916790/jaxb-unmarshalls-xml-incorrectly.  Accepting this to close the question.